# how get jquery current val() + string?

Tags: jquery

I want the textarea current val() + something string value.

I tried this code:

```js
  $("textarea").val($("textarea").val() + str);
```

The results have only have showed str.

For example,

now textarea's typing value is "abcd", and var str value is "zxcv",
and if I click a button, I want textarea's value to be "abcdzxcv".

I don't know how to get this value, how is this possible?

Comment: Do some basic debugging. What is `$("textarea").val()` returning?

Comment: so if html tag textarea's typing value is "abcd" and var str value is "zxcv", and i try  $("textarea").val($("textarea").val() + str), returning is "zxcv"

Comment: i want "abcdzxcv"

Comment: So trace back, that's telling you that val isn't returning anything. So that tells you 1. the value is empty, or 2. you're not selecting the element properly. Since the value is not empty, look at your jQuery selector: it's returning a NodeList (all textarea elements in the DOM), not the specific element. Either iterate it, or add an ID and select off of that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be the case that you have multiple textareas on your page. Try to give proper identifier as in the below snippet. Hope that helps:

https://jsfiddle.net/rxp7kzkn/5/

```
<textarea id="textData">data</textarea> 

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#textData").val("aman");
$("#textData").val($("#textData").val()+"xy");
});
```

So, in above example, initially textarea was having value `data` which was first updated to another value `aman` and then concatenate with another string `xy`. You can simply update the value of textarea by simply using

```
$("#textData").val()
```

Comment: Please explain your answers, the goal here is to teach, not just solve the problem.

Comment: @SterlingArcher Updated... Adding more data, so that it is easier for other people as well ending with the same issue